# make_shared (boost or stl) seems slightly slower than shared_ptr+new in my tests

Tags: c++, boost, stl, make-shared

I have a little doubt concerning what I understand about make_shared performance (boost or stl), so I wanted some opinion.

Working on an app in C++ I had to do some performance tests, and I ended up to compare make_shared and shared_ptr+new (note that it's not the performance improvement purpose, and i'm not expecting to gain time here, but i'm just curious now)

I use

- Debian Jessy x64
- liboost 1.55
- gcc 4.9.2

I read that make_shared is more efficient, and according to the explications I can find (allocation numbers, overhead) it seems logical to me (as far as I can understand).

But doing a quick and stupid test, I don't understand what I get

```
        std::shared_ptr<MyUselessClass> dummyPtr = std::shared_ptr<MyUselessClass>(new MyUselessClass());
    auto start = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() ;

    // - STD Share
    std::shared_ptr<MyUselessClass> stdSharePtr = std::shared_ptr<MyUselessClass>(new MyUselessClass());
    auto stdSharePtrTime_1 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() ;

    // - STD Make
    std::shared_ptr<MyUselessClass> stdMakePtr = std::make_shared<MyUselessClass>();
    auto stdMakePtrTime_2 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() ;

    // - BOOST Share
    boost::shared_ptr<MyUselessClass> boostSharePtr = boost::shared_ptr<MyUselessClass>(new MyUselessClass());
    auto boostSharePtrTime_3 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() ;

    // - BOOST Make
    boost::shared_ptr<MyUselessClass> boostMakePtr = boost::make_shared<MyUselessClass>();
    auto boostMakePtrTime_4 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() ;

    boost::chrono::nanoseconds stdShare = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::nanoseconds>(stdSharePtrTime_1-start) ;
    boost::chrono::nanoseconds stdMake = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::nanoseconds>(stdMakePtrTime_2-stdSharePtrTime_1) ;
    boost::chrono::nanoseconds boostShare = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::nanoseconds>(boostSharePtrTime_3-stdMakePtrTime_2) ;
    boost::chrono::nanoseconds boostMake = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::nanoseconds>(boostMakePtrTime_4-boostSharePtrTime_3) ;

    cout << "---" << endl ;
    cout << "STD   share " << stdShare << endl ;
    cout << "BOOST share " << boostShare << endl ;
    cout << "STD   make " << stdMake << endl ;
    cout << "BOOST make " << boostMake << endl ;
```

MyUselessClass is a simple class with 3 class attributes (sting, bool, int), and only constructor and desctructor.

The "results" (I quote because it's not an accurate test, of course) are the following (i runned it into a loop to get many iterations, gives in average the same results) :

```
    STD   share 162 nanoseconds
    BOOST share 196 nanoseconds
    STD   make 385 nanoseconds
    BOOST make 264 nanoseconds
```

If I believe my test, make_shared is slightly slower than calling share_ptr & new instanciation. I would have expected, if I were to see any differences as nanoseconds precision, the contrary ...

So now I am wondering:

- Maybe my test is too stupid, nanosecons order has no importance in those operations ?
- Maybe I missed a point in the explanation of better performance of make_shared ?
- Maybe I missed some(serveral) point(s) in the test ?

If you have some answers of the points below, please don't hesitate :)

Thanx

Comment: You don't really want to measure only one single call of creating a shared pointer!? Please allocate a lot of pointers in a loop and compare that.

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling your program with `-O2`. I tried compiling your code without optimizations and I got similar numbers. After, compiling the code with `-O2`, make_shared is consistently faster. By the way, the size of the class `MyUselessClass` also affects the ratio of time.

Comment: Well, you probably downvoted me because I did not mention about looping. make_shared is still slower than "share" after looping for 1000000 times. I truly believe that optimization level is the reason why OP observed that make_shared is slower than "share"